# Arithmetic operations on 2 to 3 digit numbers belonging to a list

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

This is a university exercise, client-server set up where the student sets up a client and server throws random math questions for the client to solve and present.

For example, server says:

```
MATH 843 + 542 #which is a 13 element list
```

My goal is to create a code to effectively calculate the results for all operations (+-*/) as well as to make it work for both 2 and 3 digit numbers.
I found that this server message is a list and it's elements,5,6,7 and 11,12,13 need to worked upon.

Comment: Please read my edit. Note that my solution that you accepted is a dangerous solution, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Understood. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This is a lazy solution using `exec` with no precaution. The following allows the server to run any arbitrary code on your machine, so basically **don't do it**.

---

If you are sure the received line begins with `"MATH "`, then the most straightforward solution is to use `exec`.

Basically, `exec` runs the argument as Python code. For instance:

```
>>> exec("print(1 + 2)")
3
```

Besides, the code is executed in the current environment, so you can set and use variables as well:

```
>>> exec("a = 1+2")
>>> print(a)
3
```

The following code will allow you to directly perform the required computation, and to store its result in a `result` variable:

```
received = "MATH 843 + 542"
instruction = received[5:]
exec("result = {}".format(instruction))
```

---

Now just for fun: as pointed out by Stefan Pochmann, if someone knows on what address and port you're listening, they can send you a `"MATH shutil.rmtree('C:\\')"`, that will erase your computer. So once again, **don't do it**.

Comment: Worked smoothly. Thank you so much. It makes the whole process a lot more easier.

Comment: @MayankKashyap Yeah, Python is pretty straightforward for a whole lot of situations. It will often happen that you write a long and complex program, and someone comes and says "but, you could do that in five lines", or "that library already does it better". One of Python's strengths ;)

Comment: Now I just need to know the address to which I can send my `MATH shutil.rmtree('C:\\')` request.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I usually make program that don't even use sockets, so I tend not to think about these issues. I added a disclaimer at the beginning of my post (and your example at the end). I couldn't thank you enough for pointing that out. Hopefully this post can prevent people from using `exec`.

Comment: @Rightleg Slight disclaimer: In reality it'll probably have to be something like `__import__('shutil').rmtree('C:\\')`, unless `shutil` happens to be imported already. And I'm not 100% sure that `'C:\\'` is the right format and that this would all work. But I'm sure the problem is real and the short example gets the idea across. Usually I **test** even the simplest and smallest bit of code before posting it to make sure it works, but in this case I kinda didn't feel like it :-)